# Low FPS in simple SceneKit game, high wait drawable

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, metal

I'm developing a fairly simple game in SceneKit consisting of a fairly low number of nodes.

My frame rate is very low, around 20-40 FPS (ideally it would be ~60).

On using the profiler, it seems a lot of time is taken up with `Wait drawable` ~40ms in the rendering step.

Is there any reason this might be so high? It seems to be a simple Scene with 20 materials and 30K polygons, is this still too many?

[Instruments profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvalA.png)

Comment: You could use view.preferredFrameRate = 60 in your View Controller

Comment: Hi @jjdav! Read this post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012473/scenekit-ar-game-fps-getting-low-and-the-device-getting-hot-with-use/57016925#57016925 and this post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409022/fps-drop-when-adding-child-to-a-scene-arkit-scenekit/58048504#58048504